# Как преобразовать тип bytes в dictonary в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Получаю ответ от сервера, пытаюсь его преобразовать в dictonary и получаю ошибку "ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes" в чем может быть проблема?

```
p = msg.payload.decode('utf8')
d = ast.literal_eval(p)
```

сервер присылает:

> b"{'device': '/l8', 'name': 'Relay 0811'}\x00"

после декодирования:

> {'device': '/l8', 'name': 'Relay 0811'}

но дальше вылетает ошибка "ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes"

то же самое в интерпритаторе работает без проблем

```
>>> import ast
>>> s = "{'device': '/l8', 'name': 'Relay 0811'}"
>>> d = ast.literal_eval(s)
>>> d
{'device': '/l8', 'name': 'Relay 0811'}
>>> type(d)
<class 'dict'>
>>> d["device"]
'/l8'
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: В интерпретаторе не то же самое ;)

Comment: Нужно отсечь "\x00" в конце. Оно декодируется в null byte, который как тот суслик - его не видно, но он есть. А в интерпретаторе вы его не вводите, поэтому там все работает без проблем.

Comment: Почему вы выбрали для такого преобразования `ast.literal_eval()`, а не `json.loads()`?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev
json.loads() - так же выдает ошибку...

Comment: @Эникейщик
Сейчас попробую, возможно поможет :) json.loads как раз ругается на null bytes

Comment: Да я просто интересуюсь, почему такой неожиданный выбор.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev
Я что только не перебрал. И Yaml пробовал и Json и AST, и все никак...

Comment: @Эникейщик
Остался только вопрос, как отрезать эту гадость? 
это же byte и msg.payload.replace('\x00', '') не подходит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p = msg.payload.strip(b'\0').decode()
d = ast.literal_eval(p)
```

или

```
import json

d = json.loads(msg.payload.strip(b'\0'))
```

Comment: Спасибо! первый вариант сработал!
а вот 2й с json.loads выдал ошибку:

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Comment: Второй не работает потому, что в json должны использоваться двойные кавычки. Если есть возможность исправить код формирующий эти данные, то стоит это сделать.

Comment: @IlyaRU стоит явно упомянуть: не используйте `ast.literal_eval` (Питон repl для dict в данном случае), для обмена данными. Если можете, вместо этого как json передавайте.